# Rails 4 - Insert date on which a button is clicked in the db

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have a model called finalise, which has two attributes. One is a boolean called :draft and the other is a datetime called :finalised_at.  Finalise belongs to my project model. Projects has_one finalise.

The idea is that users create new projects but store them as drafts until ready to publish. In my projects show page, I have a link on my show page so that if :draft is true when the project is created, you can click the link to toggle it to false.

When :draft becomes false, I want to write: Published on [insert the date that :draft became false].

My objective is to have a link on my projects page, which is visible only to the user who created the project and only whilst :draft is true. The link says "finalise draft" and is a link which toggles the draft attribute to false. Whenever draft is false (when this link is clicked or, if a new project is created and is never saved as a draft because draft = false from the point it is created) then the date on which the project ceased to be a draft is displayed to all users on the project show page.

What I'd like to do is write a method that knows how to catch the date on which the user clicks the link to make the project :draft = false. At the moment, I have it all working, with the Time.now function instead of the time at which :draft became false.

My first attempt was:

In my finalise controller, I have:

```
  def toggle_draft
    @finalise = Finalise.find(params[:id])
    @finalise.draft = false
    @finalise.finalised = Time.now
    @finalise.save
    redirect_to project_path(Project.find(params[:projectid]))
  end
```

In my finalise view, I have:

```
<% if @project.finalise.draft == true %>

    <%= link_to 'Finalise draft', finalise_toggle_draft_path(projectid: @project.id, id: @project.finalise.id, finalise_id: @project.finalise.id), method: :patch %>
<% end %>

<% if @project.scope.finalise.draft == false %>
    <div class="datasubtextq">Published on <%= @project.scope.finalise.finalised.try(:strftime, '%d %B %Y') %></div>
<% end %>
```

I then received a suggestion below, although that user now suggests that it may not be useful for this purpose:

That suggestion involves including a method in my finalises.rb as shown below and changed my view to:

```
<% if @project.scope.finalise.draft == false %>
    <div class="datasubtextq">Published on <%= @project.scope.finalise.finalised_at.try(:strftime, '%d %B %Y') %></div>
<% end %>
```

In finalise.rb

```
def set_finalised_if_published
    if self.draft_changed? && !self.draft
      self.finalised_at = Time.now
      self.save
    end
  end
```

Using the suggestion below, I modify my finalises_controller to:

```
 def toggle_draft
    @finalise = Finalise.find(params[:id])
    @finalise.draft = false
    # @finalise.finalised = Time.now
    @finalise.save
    redirect_to project_path(@finalise.scope.project.id])
  end
```

In my routes.rb, I have:

```
resources :finalises do
   patch '/toggle-draft', to: 'finalises#toggle_draft', as: 'toggle_draft'
  end
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

```
No route matches {:action=>"toggle_draft", :controller=>"finalises", :id=>62} missing required keys: [:finalise_id]
```

I'm now afraid that trying various suggestions has made a bigger mess than that with which I made before I started this thread. I now get an error saying 'undefined method finalise'. I don't have a method called finalise. I have a model called finalise.rb

Does anyone know how to write something to catch the date on which :draft becomes equal to false in the db?

Thank you

Comment: First of all, your `toggle_draft` method doesn't toggle. It only publishes. You should probably rename that method to `publish`. Secondly, I don't see anything wrong with simply recording `Time.now` during your publish method. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve that you haven't already implemented.

Comment: Jon, I don't understand the comment relating to the toggle_draft method. I want a toggle so that :draft is toggled to false when the link is clicked. I don't think giving it a different label will change the substance of what I'm trying to do. Secondly, Time.now records the time.now. I want to know the time at which the draft was toggled to false so that I can use it elsewhere.

Comment: Well, the concept of `toggle` is a method which when executed will alter the state of an object or variable between two distinct states. If true set to false, if false set to true. However, your method only sets something to false. If it is already false and you **toggle** it, it should not really continue to be false. Secondly, `Time.now` is evaluated at the time your method is called. So it **WILL** be the time the draft was set to false.

Comment: I only display the link if the attribute is set to true. If it is false, then the link is not displayed and there is nothing to toggle. In relation to time.now, I want to use it to show the time that the toggle was applied, which works for cases where the toggle method has been applied, but not in cases where the :draft attribute has not been set to true(for it to be toggled). In that case, I want to write something that equals the date on which :draft became false, which could be the created_at date.

Comment: Yep - sounds like you should use the `created_at` date.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was worried it would use time.now as the time now when the page loads.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80653/discussion-between-jon-and-user2860931).

Comment: see comment under my answer (not sure if it sent a notification).

Comment: let me know if what I posted helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is going to be intercepting the event after it is commited to the database and before it is updated. One way to handle this is to use the current toggle_draft method you wrote and add a method to your model:

**finalise controller**

```
def toggle_draft
  @finalise = Finalise.find(params[:finalise_id])
  @finalise.draft = false

  if @finalise.save
    redirect_to project_path(@finalise.project), notice: 'Successfully Updated'
  else
    redirect_to project_path(@finalise.project), alert: 'Not Updated'
  end
end
```

Then in your **finalise.rb model file** add the following:

```
after_validation :set_publish_time
def set_publish_time
  self.finalised = Time.now  unless self.draft
end
```

Let me know if you have any questions

ALSO

For your routing issue try keep your routes to:

```
resources :finalises do
    patch 'toggle-draft', to: 'finalises#toggle_draft', as: :toggle_draft
end
```

so the route will be:

```
finalise_toggle_draft_path(@project.finalise)
```

and make sure you create the finalise record when you create the project record so it does not return nil for the id when you load in the variables into the path.

I.E.

**Product.rb model**

```
after_create :create_a_finalise
def create_a_finalise
    self.finalise.create draft: true
end
```

Other Option:

*If you use this option do not use the above after_create code*

```
def create_a_finalise_dynamic(boolean)
    self.finalise.create draft: boolean
end
```

Put it in the product#create action however it fits.

EX you could include an extra parameter checkbox in your form called 'final_draft' that is not in your database or permitted through the strong params just to know whether or not they needed a draft:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new product_params

  if @product.save
    # if the checkbox is checked make the draft value false
    boolean = params[:product][:final_draft] == 1 ? false : true
    @product.create_a_finalise_dynamic boolean
    redirect_to projects_path, notice: 'Created!'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but I get this error when I test: undefined method `finalise' for #<Project:0x000001043bf010>
It's referring to the final step in create_a_finalise

Comment: Also, will the final method interfere with someone who creates a new project which is never a draft?

Comment: are you relationships setup correctly? Product: has_one :finalise ;; Finalise: belongs_to :project

Comment: it would always make a draft, feel free to update it or make the call to the method with a variable passed in by not having it be a after_create method. I updated my answer

Comment: I mean that a user completes the draft in one go, so draft is always false, then the first option in your product.rb model might not allow that false answer to save on create. What do you mean by the final line 'put it in the product#create action? How do I do that?

Comment: Also, do I need the after create:create a finalise in option 2 of the product model?

Comment: I get this error with my project controller when I try this: undefined local variable or method `create_a_finalise' for

Comment: I'll answer this for you tomorrow

Comment: so if you are going to use the second option (create_a_finalise_dynamic) you do not want to use the after_create hook or method. I've updated the end of my answer to show you how you might best use it

Comment: Hi, I don't understand the final option. I am getting an error when I try to create a new project that says: undefined local variable or method `create_a_finalise' for #<Scope:0x00000105b770e0>
Scope belongs to project and has one :finalise. Scope belongs to project. That error is pointing to the create action in the projects controller. If I delete the after create callback from scope.rb, then the way I read your example, I need to add to my projects create action to have a chained event on project.scope.finalise create a finalise. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I tried this, without the boolean final draft line, but I get this error: undefined local variable or method `boolean' for #<ProjectsController:0x0000010e983aa0>

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use ActiveRecord callbacks, like `after_save`. In this callback, you can watch the changes in the model with the methods provided by the module ActiveModel::Dirty.

Example, in your `Finalize` model:

```
after_save :set_finalized_if_published

def set_finalized_if_published
  if self.draft_changed? && !self.draft
    self.finalized = Time.now
    self.save
  end
end
```

Comment: By the way, I think that to follow Rails convention, you should have named your attribute `finalized_at`. With `finalized`, we expect that it's a boolean.

Comment: Hi - this option looks sensible. I'll try it. What is ActiveModel::Dirty? Does !self.draft mean "the :draft attribute is not true?"

Comment: Also, where do you find these conventions? Is there a list of them somewhere?

Comment: And - does that mean I don't need the controller method? Do I need something else in my view, which (after changing the name of the attribute to :finalised_at) is set out in the main body above

Comment: When I try this, I get an error that says: undefined local variable or method `set_finalised_at_if_published' in my projects controller. I have inserted the method in my finalised model. Finalise belongs to scope, which in turn belongs to project. Project accepts nested attributes for scope (and finalise is nested within that)

Comment: @user2860931  `Finalise` is a model that resided in your `app/models/` directory, right? You don't have to do anything in the controller, Rails deals with the callbacks alone. Basically, the `after_save` callbacks tells rails to automatically execute the `set_finalized_if_published` method each time a `Finalise` object is saved. This method checks if the `draft` attribute has changed, and if it has been set to `false` (hence `!self.draft` is evaluated as `true`). If this is the case, the `finalized` attribute is updated with `Time.now`.

Comment: @user2860931 so the code in your controller is the same that the code you posted in your question, except that you should remove `@finalise.finalised = Time.now` because this is now taken care of by the callback.

Comment: I get this error: undefined local variable or method `set_finalised_at_if_published' for #<Finalise:0x0000010ae73f50>

Comment: Yes. finalise is a model in my models directory

Comment: Yes, i copied my updated finalises_controller above. The error is referencing the projects controller

Comment: Check for typo maybe. I wrote it with a `z`, not a `s` (sorry, I'm not a native english speaker)

Comment: The error references a problem with that line above, but highlights the projects controller rather than the finalise controller. Do I need to do something in the projects_controller to get this to work?

Comment: Now, at the end of the question, the method is `set_finalised_if_published`, and in your comment above, it's `set_finalised_at_if_published`. Have you checked for typos _everywhere_?

Comment: that got that part, but now I get this route error: No route matches {:action=>"toggle_draft", :controller=>"finalises", :id=>62} missing required keys: [:finalise_id]

Comment: This is another problem, so you should ask another question. Also, I read your question again, and actually I'm not sure of what you want. Anyway, callbacks are really useful in a lot of situations, so I suggest you read the doc: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html.

Comment: ok. well thanks then. I'll keep trying to figure out a solution.